# how to free resources after spaw process?

Tags: node.js, spawn

```
for (i = 0; i < 1030; i++)
{
    var fs = require("fs")
    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn

    var log = fs.openSync("./program.log", "a")

    var child = spawn("./program", [], {detached: true, stdio: ["ignore", log, log]})
    child.unref()
}
```

I have ulimit for count open files by process 1024 and after execution this code have ENOENT error

I can increase limit to other value, but in this case I don't need log file descriptor anymore. How to deatch this fd after pass it into spawn?

Answer (score 0):

ENOENT means that the file/directory does not exist. It doesn't mean that you have too much files open. The error that happens when too much files are open is EMFILE.

However, ENOENT should not happen as this:

```
var log = fs.openSync("./program.log", "a")
```

Should create a file if it does not exist.

The error happens in the child process or in the parent process? Are the child processes using any files?

as per open(2) man:

```
   ENOENT O_CREAT is not set and the named file does not exist.  Or, a
          directory component in pathname does not exist or is a
          dangling symbolic link.

   ENOENT pathname refers to a nonexistent directory, O_TMPFILE and one
          of O_WRONLY or O_RDWR were specified in flags, but this kernel
          version does not provide the O_TMPFILE functionality.
```

Your error should be the second alternative, as your openSync call will create the file.

Is the `./program` in your current folder?

Comment: parent process cannot create more child process because haven't any free descriptors

Comment: ENOENT means that the file/directory does not exist - yes! because parent process cant create more than 1024 files (ulimit)! That is why I need close file but spawn() need work too...

Comment: `EMFILE The per-process limit on the number of open file descriptors
              has been reached (see the description of RLIMIT_NOFILE in
              getrlimit(2)).`

this is the error for too many files open. Can you post the exact error line? as in what's printed on your terminal?

Are you sure the `./program` exists in the folder you are calling your program from?

Answer (score 0):

fs.close(log) after spawn fix trouble